# Авто генерация итемов кроме ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, view

Товарищи, доброго времени суток! Чисто теоретический вопрос, есть понимание, как настроить автогенерацию итемов в ListView через ViewModel, путем присвоения к параметру ItemsSource своего списка с итемами, а каким образом можно так же сгенерировать данные из списка, если я спроектировал свой шаблон из StackLayout

Пример View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="test1.Views.itemsView" >

<ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  />
        <Label Text="{Binding Family}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding age}"  />    
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Не понятно, что вы хотите. Чтобы в StackLayout находились элементы из списка(или привязаны к ней) как в ListView(тобишь все тоже самое, только контейнером является StackLayout, а не ListView) или StackLayout являлся бы контейнером конкретного элемента?

Comment: В ваших мыслях немного запутался) по простому, чтобы вместо ячеек ListView были ячейки StackLayout.
есть два объекта в списке, в каждом объекте имя, фамилия и возраст, разработан шаблон под каждый элемент, пример выше, в Итоге во View должно сгенерироваться 2 StackLayout

Comment: ListView, а в нем ячейки StackLayout или любой другой контейнер(не ListView), а в нем ячейки StackLayout? Почему ListView не устраивает кстати(любопытство)?

Comment: Чисто теоретический вопрос, я только разбираюсь в Xamarin и интересно услышать бы совет. Например если необходимо вывести список чего либо, например той же самой новостной ленты в вк в моб приложении, они тоже юзают listView?

Comment: Я не в курсе, как делает вк(может быть у них самописные Controls), но ListView подразумевает отображения информации в любом виде. В вашем случае вывод кучи StackLayout. Отвечаю на ваш вопрос: самый простой способ отобразить информацию, отличную от текстовой в виде List - ListView. Все остальное танцы с бубном, которые в данном случае вряд ли вам будут нужны. Просто используйте ваш StackLayout в виде элементы ListView. Если нужны доп.фукнции - изменяйте шаблон\пишите свой контрол\гуглите паки контролов.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ) Так и думал, что не стоит изобретать велосипед)

Comment: Городить можно(не совсем уверен как в Xamarin), но в WPF любой контрол можно ворочать как вздумается. Вопрос в том, надо ли это. Просто если задача не имеет специфических особенностей, это не нужно. Если вопрос теоретический - то ответ на него долгий и сложный(изложить все варианты с выкладками и так далее).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ от Arantler
Спасибо за ответ! =)
Самый простой способ отобразить информацию, отличную от текстовой в виде List - ListView. Все остальное танцы с бубном, которые в данном случае вряд ли вам будут нужны. Просто используйте ваш StackLayout в виде элементы ListView. Если нужны доп.фукнции - изменяйте шаблон\пишите свой контрол\гуглите паки контролов.